# $L_2$ integrability of function composition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, hilbert-spaces

Let $f:R^n \rightarrow R^n$ and $g:R^n\rightarrow R$. Suppose that $g$ is square integrable, i.e. $\int_{R^n}|g(x)|^2 dx < \infty$. Under what conditions on $f$ (if any) is it appropriate to say that $g\circ f$ is also square integrable? The measure here is the Lesbegue measure on $R^n$.

Comment: I think it is sufficient for $f$ to be a bijection but I am not sure what  a necessary condition would be.

Comment: Sufficient: $|\det Df| \ge c > 0$.

Comment: @user251257 and the proof would be $df(x) = Df dx$ so $$\int_{R^n} g(f(x))dx = \int_{R^n} g(f(x)) Df^{-1}df(x),$$
or is it more subtle?

Comment: @SZN you should probably revisit the change of variables formula in $\mathbb R^n$. But basically that is it.